# Should there be play in rear brake

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, brakes

My rear wheel can move about an inch when the brake is completely locked. The movement is in the connection between the hub and the disk. As you can see in the picture below, the disk is held to the hub by 6 bolts and there seems to be another piece of connector metal between the screws. This connector piece with the screws seems to be moving with the wheel while the brake rotor does not. You can see a video of the wheel moving here https://streamable.com/g6k0ci. I'm wondering if this play is normal, or if the bolts are just not tight enough. The rotors are Shimano SM-RT66, 180mm, and it is on the 2021 Nukeproof scout 290 comp https://nukeproof.com/products/2021-scout-290. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: That connecter metal piece is Shimano’s “anti-loosening washer”.

Comment: Is it supposed to have movement, or is it loose, or broken?

Comment: Are the disk mounting bolts tight?  Is the there movement between the disk surface and the face of the hub?

Answer (score 8):

The video shows a broken hub. It should be impossible under all circumstances for the hub shell to move relative to the rotor. I can't tell from your pictures but I'm guessing that what's happening here is it's some kind of multi-piece shell as opposed to the shell being one piece, and the interface has failed.

Comment: Thanks. I might bring it into an LBS and have them diagnose it. It's a new bike so if it's broken then I'll contact the seller (CRC).

Comment: @JackN If it's a new bike, that you didn't buy at your local bike shop, then you shouldn't go show it to them before returning it. You are just wasting their time. You bought a bike online, endangering the continued existence of your local bike shop. And now you want your local bike shop to support you (i.e. give you free time/money), because presumably you aren't going to pay for a diagnosis. And if the LBS is a good one, of course they'll be polite if you go there, after all you are a potential future customer. That's no reason to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue because the ring holding the disk got loose. It is certainly worth checking that everything is tighten to the proper torque (usually written on the part).